# Ionic ngStyle Background image dynamically

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am Trying to bind my ngStyle Background image on my card

Here's my code:

```
        <ion-slides slidesPerView="1" centeredSlides (ionSlideWillChange)= "slideChange($event)" [ngStyle]= "{'background-image': 'url('+ bg +')'}">
```

my TS file

```
  bg = "images/sample.jpg"
```

I used also this.bg and 'background' instead of 'background-image' but nothing happened. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing it correctly, here is a [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-y19dzx?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

```
<ion-slides slidesPerView="1" centeredSlides (ionSlideWillChange)= "slideChange($event)" [ngStyle]= "{'background-image': 'url('+ bg +')'}">
Test Content for aJaysanity
</ion-slides>
```

If you check developer tools, do you see a 404 error for the image which you have set?